# Cakephp: Can AppError determine which page caused an error?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP's AppError to email myself any errors that occur. This works great except I can't figure out *which* pages are causing errors.

For example, *BadPage* links to an image that doesn't exist. AppError emails me that the image doesn't exist, but doesn't say anything about *BadPage*. Is there any way to see that *BadPage* is where the error originated?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can access $url = $this->controller->here; from within your error handler.

Comment: Good thought, but $this->controller is what caused the error. In the OP example, the controller is Img (rather than BadPage).

Comment: Hmm, I wounder if it would help to access the referrer?  That, in theory, would be the page that linked to the image.